# python regex: Is there a flag value for NOT ignorecase?

Tags: python, regex

When doing regex matching, we do

```
re.match(regex, text)
```

To ignore case we could do

```
re.match(regex, text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Is there a flag/value for **NOT ignore case**?

Would like to keep my code a bit more cleaner by not doing

```
if XXX:
    re.match(regex, text, re.IGNORECASE)
else:
    re.match(regex, text)
```

It would be great if I could do sth like

```
re.match(regex, text, re.IGNORECASE if XXX else re.NOTIGNORE)
```

Comment: Have you tried `re.match(regex, text, flags=(re.IGNORECASE if XXX else 0))`

Comment: don't feel comfortable using the actual int value, as I may forget what it means after a while.

Comment: Yes, there is... the absence of the `re.IGNORECASE`. When it is not there, the regex engine does case sensitive matching by default. Introducing more verbose code does not make your code cleaner or concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible for Python/re library.

The flag is a int value. You can try with different values. None would work. See details in https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects

Answer (score 2):

How about :

```
NOTIGNORECASE = 0
re.match(regex, text, flags=(re.IGNORECASE if XXX else NOTIGNORECASE))
```